# Magento 2 not return array from Block

Tags: magento2

How to send array from Block and get in Phtml file in magento 2. i am trying to return array from Block and wants to get array in template Phtml file. But they do not show my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to define any public function in your **Block** as

```
public function getMyCustomData(){
    $arr = [];
    $arr[] = // my data;
    ...
    ...

    return $arr;
}
```

than in your **phtml** file you can call this function by

```
$myCustomArr = $block->getMyCustomData();
```

Comment: Its Working Thanks :)